# How to call a javascript function with Lift after clicking a button?

Tags: button, lift, google-visualization

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string','Year');
      data.addColumn('number','D1');
      data.addColumn('number','D2');
      data.addRows(2);
      data.setValue(0,0,'1900');
      data.setValue(1,0,'1910');
      data.setValue(0,1,1);
      data.setValue(1,1,2);
      data.setValue(0,2,3);
      data.setValue(1,2,1);
      var options = {title: 'Tree Chart',
                     hAxis: {title: 'Time',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                     pointSize: 5};
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  function showChart(){  
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  }

</script>
<form class="form-inline lift:form.ajax">
<div class="lift:DChart.render">
<button id="getChart" value="Get Chart" class="btn btn-inverse">Get Chart</button>
</div>
</form>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

the `showChart()` function displays the chart in `chart_div`

Here's my Lift code:

```scala
object DChart {
        def render = {
          def process():JsCmd = Run("showChart();")
          "#getChart"  #> SHtml.button("Get Chart", process)
        }
   }
```

Clicking on the button should execute the `showChart()` function.. sadly it doesn't work..

Please help me understand how to run the script function from lift!

Comment: What if you replace `showChart()` with `alert(1)` ? What is it showing in this case ?

Comment: @Vasya: even with alert() method nothing is displayed.

Comment: @jcern: thx for your ansewers, however it doesen't work yet (all 3 examples).. Yes your are right, I'm doing something more complicated but I'm stuck with this issue and I' don't get how to solve the bug. I'm quite new in front-end development (3 weeks), so this may seems a stupid issue for most of you. The choice of Liftweb it's imposed by the project so I have to work out a solution.  
Anyway it's strange, when i call showChart() in HTML "raw" the chart is nicely dispayed, so the method is really working, but when I try to run the script from lift nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHtml.button` takes as an argument `() => Any` so any JavaScript will not get returned to the browser and executed.

I would do one of two things:

1. Use `SHtml.ajaxButton` instead since the method body expects a `JsCmd` return
2. Bind the event instead, like: `"#getChart [onclick]" #> SHtml.onEvent((str) => process())`

Both do essentially the same thing and should get your code working. Option 1 will replace your entire HTML button with the one lift renders, Option 2 will just add the ajax to an `onclick` event on the existing HTML button.

I assume you'll be doing something more complicated, and actually want to make an ajax call - but if you just want to add the `showChart()` call clientside, you can simply say: `"#getChart [onclick]" #> process().toJsCmd`

Comment: you're right thx, but to solve the problem just use drawChart() instead of showChart()

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was the problem.. I was calling the method `showChart()` but this method uses the google function `setOnLoadCallback()` so the chart could be displayed only if the method is called loading the page (from what I've understood so far).

The solution: just call the `drawChart()` method instead!
I've tryed every of the solution posted from jcern with the `drawChart()` method, all are working.

thx jcern :)